# Markup and Execution of HTML, CSS and JavaScript from seperate textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I found a code for real time markup for HTML and CSS in different textareas using a jQuery function that outputs in an iframe:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container grid">
   <form>
      <h3>HTML</h3>
      <textarea id="html" class="edit"></textarea>     // TEXTAREA FOR HTML

      <h3>CSS</h3>
      <textarea id="css" class="edit"></textarea>       // TEXTAREA FOR CSS
   </form>
</div>
<div class="output grid">
   <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

**JQUERY** for markup

```
function() {
   $(".grid").height($(window).height());

   var contents = $("iframe").contents(),
       body = contents.find("body"),
       styleTag = $("<style></style>").appendTo(contents.find("head"));

   $("textarea.edit").keyup(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.attr("id") === "html") {
         body.html($this.val());
      } else {
         // it had to be css
         styleTag.text($this.val());
      }
   });
})();
```

What if I wanted another textarea for javascript? I'm guessing you can't execute it in real time so I have to include a button to to run an `eval()`
But how?

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML you can have another textarea for the javascript code.

In your textarea.edit event handler, you can add another check for javascript and use something like this -

```
$iframeEl.append(`<script>${textarea.val()}</script>`);
```

This line would execute your script as well because the browser re parses the document whenever it encounters a DOM change and it would also execute the script tag.

We should anyways refrain on using the eval keyword because it is an expensive operation and is advised not to be used.

Comment: I'm really sorry bro, but how would you append it to the existing jquery function? I'm raw and trying to learn jquery

Comment: Do you mean append function?

Comment: jQuery provides the append function and inside it i have just used string literal which is a new feature in es6. 
Obviously $iframeEl is the jquery element for the iframe.